# Apple-app-site-association returning 500 from validation and working as expected in browser and curl

Tags: nginx, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

Here is my nginx configuration

```
server {
   root /home/ubuntu/www
   ...
   location = /apple-app-site-association {
        default_type 'application/json';
   }
   location = /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
        default_type 'application/json';
   }
    ...
}
```

and the curl output is

```
› curl -I https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/json
vary: Accept-Encoding
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
accept-ranges: bytes
```

However apple is giving me this, any idea?

[image: Apple-app-site-association]

Comment: Have you tried to request the web server with an external server (or service like https://reqbin.com/curl ) sending the request rather using your own computer? I've been tricked before by my own computer for problems like this ;)

Comment: What is the corresponding line from the nginx error log?

Comment: @imgg curl give me expected result, content type and json output

Comment: @IvanShatsky why do you think there is an error? As per the implementation the page should deliver with content type json and json output in browser which is happening accurately. Am I missing something?

Comment: @niksmac I don't know what is the reason of this issue, but every 50x error had an according entry in the nginx error log. Checking it may give some clue on how to fix this.

Comment: @IvanShatsky calls form Search API Validation Tool are not even reaching my server, nothing in access or error log.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I am getting this error it turns out to be apple bot `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 17.58.99.163, server: 0.0.0.0:443, upstream: "127.0.0.1:5349", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0`

Comment: All I can tell is that you need to find out how that request differ from the `curl` one. This error log line should be followed with the request line, check it and try to reproduce exactly that request with the `curl`. Check the TLS ciphers you are using via the `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/` - are there any anomalies with the Apple systems?